# No matching method compiler error

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to call a method in C++ language.

Here is the method defenition

```
  static responseID
  sell(ToteGateway* toteToUse,
       gdi_t gdi,
       char* accountID,
       int pin,
       int card,
       int race,
       pennies* stake,
       int betType,
       runnerList* legRunners,
       int numLegs,
       pennies* ticketCost,
       pennies* salesTax,
       pennies* accessCharge,
       tfaddress* sellAddress,
       pennies* availableBalance,
       char* tsnNumber,
       pennies* holdBalance,
       pennies initial_balance,
       char force_to_one_leg,
       char* yourSerialNumber,
       int64_t* cisTktID,
       char* cisAlias,
       uint32_t spfavs);
```

And here is how I'm calling it

```
 returnValue = Account::sell(toteGateway, myGdi, accountID, pin, card, race, stake,
           nBetType, theRunners, numLegs, &ticketCost, &salesTax, &accessCharge, &sellAddress,
           &availableBalance, (char*)&theTkt, &holdBalance, 1,yourSerialNumber,cisTktID,cisAlias,spfavs);
      LOG_DEBUG_MSG(" After Executing  Account::sell");
```

The below error occurring after adding the last 4 parameters, here the values I'm passing like

```
  char* yourSerialNumber = (char*)ns1__accountSell->yourSerialNumber.c_str();
      int64_t cisTktID = (int64_t)ns1__accountSell->cisTktID;
      char* cisAlias =(char*)ns1__accountSell->cisAlias.c_str();
      uint32_t  spfavs = ns1__accountSell->spfavs;
```

And passing these values to the method. And I endup with an error like

> src/atlserverservice.cpp:1360: error: no matching function for call to ‘Account::sell(ToteGateway*&, uint32_t&, char*&, int&, int&, int&, pennies&, int&, runnerList [10], int&, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, tfaddress*, pennies*, char*, pennies*, int, char*&, int64_t*, char*&, uint32_t*)’
>
> Account.h:509: note: candidates are: static responseID Account::sell(ToteGateway*, gdi_t, char*, int, int, int, pennies, int, runnerList*, int, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, tfaddress*, pennies*, char*, pennies*, pennies, char)
>
> Account.h:567: note:                 static responseID Account::sell(ToteGateway*, gdi_t, char*, int, int, int, pennies*, int, runnerList*, int, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, tfaddress*, pennies*, char*, pennies*, pennies, char, char*)
>
> Account.h:591: note:                 static responseID Account::sell(ToteGateway*, gdi_t, char*, int, int, int, pennies*, int, runnerList*, int, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, tfaddress*, pennies*, char*, pennies*, pennies, char, char*, int64_t*, char*)
>
> Account.h:616: note:                 static responseID Account::sell(ToteGateway*, gdi_t, char*, int, int, int, pennies*, int, runnerList*, int, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, tfaddress*, pennies*, char*, pennies*, pennies, char, char*, int64_t*, char*, uint32_t)
>
> Account.h:633: note:                 static responseID Account::sell(ToteGateway*, gdi_t, char*, int, int, int, int, wager_data*, int, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, char*, tfaddress*, pennies*)

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Is that the full error text?

Comment: You're passing `cisTktID ` as an `int64_t` but your function definition defines `int64_t*`, I think you want `int64_t* cisTktID = (int64_t*)ns1__accountSell->cisTktID;` or pass the address

Comment: This is C++, not C. Please be aware which language you're using.

Comment: Your question is for C but you are in C++ , please update to C++ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `&cisTktID` to pass an address not a value.

Comment: No. It is still the same error. I'm using the declarations `int64_t* cisTktID = (int64_t*)ns1__accountSell->cisTktID;
      char* cisAlias =(char*)ns1__accountSell->cisAlias.c_str();
      uint32_t*  spfavs = (uint32_t*)ns1__accountSell->spfavs;` and passing the values like `Account::sell(toteGateway, myGdi, accountID, pin, card, race, stake,
           nBetType, theRunners, numLegs, &ticketCost, &salesTax, &accessCharge, &sellAddress,
           &availableBalance, (char*)&theTkt, &holdBalance, 1,yourSerialNumber,cisTktID,cisAlias,spfavs);
`

Comment: Why did you change `spfavs` now?  You should not have.  Do you understand what it means for the function arguments to be pointers or not?

Comment: That is just a try. I kept it same and ran with your fix. It gave me the same error. `error: no matching function for call to ‘Account::sell(ToteGateway*&, uint32_t&, char*&, int&, int&, int&, pennies&, int&, runnerList [10], int&, pennies*, pennies*, pennies*, tfaddress*, pennies*, char*, pennies*, int, char*&, int64_t*, char*&, uint32_t*)’` Hence tried that. Now I reverted the `spfavs` but still no luck

Comment: What is the full and complete error message?  It should tell you what you passed, not only what it expected.

Comment: Here is the complete messages in side compiler. http://pastebin.com/Z1mhPYep  I don't see any other error message other than that line. All others are warnings  L.No 282 is what I'm worrying about.

Comment: Please help me. I'm a Java guy and for some reason, I have to work on this.

Comment: So in your most recent error messages, the last parameter is being passed a pointer, whereas it needs to be a value.  If you still have `uint32_t  spfavs` you need to pass `spfavs` as the last argument.  If you now have `uint32_t* spfavs` then pass `*spfavs` to dereference the pointer.